# Do any AspectJ based profiler packages exist?

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I'm building a Spring 3.2.4 app, and am looking for something quick and easy to use for profiling my code.  I've searched the net and am very surprised I can't find anything specific for this.  I know I can easily write up my own AspectJ profiler and create my own @Profiled annotation, but it seems like something fairly common that should already exist.

I would rather not use a Spring-AOP only solution as Spring-AOP has limitations (ie: only public methods, etc), but if something nice exists, I might be convinced.

I would have thought that Spring might have a library for this already, but can't find anything on the Spring site or on Apache Commons.

Comment: Why does it need to be AspectJ? What do you need to do that isn't handled by standard profilers?

Comment: By standard profilers, I presume you mean things like jProfiler, AnyKit, etc.  I forgot to include that in my post.  I didn't want something where i would need extra agents/tools (ex: jProfiler, etc) to do full indepth profiling.  I just want to be able to see amount of time specific methods take to execute.

Comment: http://www.christianschenk.org/blog/profiling-with-aspectj/ and a zillion other references--it's tens of lines at the most, although there might be some Maven packages that do it I suppose.

Comment: @DaveNewton  Thanks.  I agree; I found a bunch of sample code just like that one or http://thoughtforge.net/713/creating-a-profiling-aspect-with-spring-aop-and-aspectj/ and like you said a bunch of others.  But am hoping for a "maintained?" packaged maven artifact that I can just drop in directly as opposed to cut&paste someone's code.

Answer (score 1):

Non-AspectJ ideas:

An out of the box solution would be [Spring Insight](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nBqSh7nVNzc) but it's quite heavy and runs only in tc server. As lightweight alternatives you have two built-in interceptor in Spring:

- [PerformanceMonitorInterceptor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/aop/interceptor/PerformanceMonitorInterceptor.html)
- [JamonPerformanceMonitorInterceptor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/aop/interceptor/JamonPerformanceMonitorInterceptor.html)

Just setup one of them and it will intercept the proxied method calls in your app. [An article about the usage.](http://www.javaworld.com/community/node/3763)

In case you need something custom you might get some inspiration from [this post](http://gadget.greenformatics.hu/performance-monitoring-of-spring-applications).